# change name aggregation fields mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing an aggregation in MongoDB and I would like to change the name of the reference fields:

This is my aggregation:

```
[

    {"$ match": {
    "attrName": {$ in: arr}}},
    {"$ group": {
        "_id": {
            "recvTime": "$ recvTime",
            "attrName": "$ attrName",
            "attrValue": "$ attrValue"
        }
    }},
    {"$ group": {
        "_id": "$ _id.attrName",
        "dates": {
            "$ push": {
                "recvTime": "$ _id.recvTime",
                "attrValue": "$ _id.attrValue"

            },
        },
    }}
    ]
```

This is your answer:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "var_ContadorRiego",
        "dates": [
            {
                "recvTime": "2018-03-24T01: 18: 18.619Z",
                "attrValue": "12"
            },
            {
                "recvTime": "2018-03-25T01: 18: 18.619Z",
                "attrValue": "19"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "var_TempExt",
        "dates": [
            {
                "recvTime": "2018-03-25T01: 18: 18.619Z",
                "attrValue": "16.511116"
            },
            {
                "recvTime": "2018-03-24T01: 18: 18.619Z",
                "attrValue": "12.511116"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like that where it says _id put name, where it puts recvTime put name and where it puts attrValue put value.

final goal like this:

```
[
     {
         "name": "var_ContadorRiego",
         "dates": [
             {
                 "name": "2018-03-24T01: 18: 18.619Z",
                 "value": "12"
             },
             {
                 "name": "2018-03-25T01: 18: 18.619Z",
                 "value": "19"
             }
         ]
     },
     {
         "name": "var_TempExt",
         "dates": [
             {
                 "name": "2018-03-25T01: 18: 18.619Z",
                 "value": "16.511116"
             },
             {
                 "name": "2018-03-24T01: 18: 18.619Z",
                 "value": "12.511116"
             }
         ]
     }
]
```

This can be done directly from the aggregation? Or do I have to go through the whole object and make the changes?

Greetings and thank you.

Comment: Change the last two stages to `{"$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.attrName",
        "dates": {
            "$push": {
                "name": "$ _id.recvTime",
                "value": "$ _id.attrValue"
            }
        }
    }},
    {"$project":{"name":"$_id", "_id":0, "dates":1}}`

Comment: Hello, this worked for me but it shows the id name in last position as I could put it at the beginning?[
    {
        "dates": [
            {
                "name": "var_TempExt",
                "value": "16.511116"
            },
            {
                "name": "var_TempExt",
                "value": "12.511116"
            }
        ],
        "name": "var_TempExt"
    }
]

Answer (score 0):

First change the 2nd **$group** by:

```
{"$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.attrName",
    "dates": {
        "$ push": {
            "time": "$_id.recvTime",
            "name": "$_id.attrName",
            "value": "$ _id.attrValue"
        },
    },
}}
```

And then use **$project** at the end of your aggregation pipeline for renaming _id field.

```
{ $project: {  
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id",
   }
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: hello, I work with what the comrade says adding the dates: 1

but the id name appears at the end

[{"dates": [{"name": "var_TempExt", "value": "16.511116"}, {"name": "var_TempExt", "value": "12.511116"}], "name": "var_TempExt "}]

Comment: @Manolait put dates:1 at the end in $project.